# ¿Cómo hago un texto multilínea en CSS y JS?

Tags: javascript, html, css, html5, css3

Resulta que estoy haciendo una To-Do List en JavaScript, todo funciona bien, el problema viene en que cuando escribo una tarea ésta se escribe en una sola línea, no hace saltos de línea como sería lo ideal al sobrepasar el contenedor.

He intentado con la propiedad ***text-overflow:ellipsis***, pero no me ha funcionado...

También he intentado modificar el ***padding*** y el ***margin***, pero no hubo manera de que la tarea realice un salto de línea en el momento que llega a sobrepasar el ***border***. ¿Alguien sabe que es lo que puede estar fallando? Mil gracias de antemano!

Adjunto código:

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <title>Insertar HTML</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="alert">
        <p class="tareas">No hay tareas pendientes.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="datos">
        <div class="resultados">
            <ul>
                
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="container">
        <div class="input">
            <form>
                <input type="text" placeholder="Escribe aquí" name="Insertar texto" id="texto">
                <input type="submit" value="Registrar" id="btn">
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>

    

</body>
<script src="/script.js"></script>
</html>
```

CSS

```
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat:ital,wght@0,300;0,400;0,500;1,100;1,400&display=swap');

*{
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-family: 'Montserrat';
}

body{
    background-color: rgb(110, 64, 218);
}

.input{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    margin-top: 200px;
}

form{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    margin-top: 0px;
    width: 80%;
}

input{
    margin-top: 15px;
}
    /* datos */


.datos{
    text-align: center;
}

#btn{
    width: 30%;
    margin-left: 350px;
    height: 50px;
}

#texto{
    height: 50px;
}

li{
    list-style: none;
}

.resultados li p:hover{
    background-color: rgb(220, 43, 226);
}

.resultados li p{
    background-color: rgb(97, 28, 161);
    color: white;
    width: 50%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    border: 1px solid;
    border-radius: 20px;
    padding-left: 5px;
}

.resultados{
    border: 10px;
    border-color: black;
}

.alert{
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 50px;
    display: none;
}

#texto{
    border: 2px solid rgb(158, 77, 127);
    border-radius: 10px;
}

#texto:focus{
    background-color: rgb(233, 233, 76);
    border: 5px solid ;
    border-color: blueviolet;
}

#btn{
    border: 1px solid rgb(101, 45, 192);
    border-radius: 10px;

}

#btn:hover{
    background-color: blueviolet;
    color: white;
    border: 2px solid ;
    border-color: yellowgreen;
}



.tareas{
    color: white;
}
```

JS

```
const btn = document.querySelector('#btn')
const input = document.querySelector('#texto')
const resultados = document.querySelector('.resultados')
const li = document.querySelector("li");
const ul = document.querySelector("ul")
const alert = document.querySelector(".alert")



btn.addEventListener('click', (e) =>{
    e.preventDefault()

    const text = input.value;

    if (text != "") {
        const li = document.createElement("li");
        const p = document.createElement("p");
        
        p.textContent = text;

        ul.appendChild(li);
        li.appendChild(p);
        p.appendChild(addDeleteBtn());
        alert.style.display = "none";
       
    }

    input.value = "";
})


function addDeleteBtn() {
    const deleteBtn = document.createElement("button");
  
    deleteBtn.textContent = "X";
    deleteBtn.className = "btn-delete";
    deleteBtn.style.margin = "10px 0px 0px 605px";
    deleteBtn.style.padding = "5px";
  
    deleteBtn.style.color="black";
    
  
    deleteBtn.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
      const item = e.target.parentElement.parentElement;
      ul.removeChild(item);
  
      const items = document.querySelectorAll("li");
  
      if (items.length === 0){ alert.style.display = "block";}
    
    });
  
    return deleteBtn;
  }
```

Comment: Aquí tengo un [proyecto](https://codepen.io/christopher-ps/pen/KKorPPq) preparado, puede que te ayude un poco.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El código  hace lo que le estás diciendo, que en cada **li** añada al final un botón, además con un espaciado muy grande, y eso queda mal maquetado.

Yo lo haría así.

Primero, crearía tres clases de estilos de la siguiente manera

```
.linea{
    display: flex;
}
.texto-linea{
    flex: 1 1 auto;
    text-align: left;
}
.boton-linea{
    flex: 0 0 40px;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Quitaría las etiquetas **ul** y pondría un **div**, así

```
<div class="resultados">
    <div id="contenedor">
        
    </div>
</div>
```

Quitaría estas dos líneas

```
const li = document.querySelector("li");
const ul = document.querySelector("ul")
```

y las sustituiría por esta

```
const contenedor = document.querySelector("#contenedor")
```

El bloque en donde se cosntruye la línea lo haría así

```
    if (text != "") {
        const linea = document.createElement("div");
        const textoLinea = document.createElement("div");
        const botonLinea = document.createElement("div");
        linea.className = "linea";
        textoLinea.className = "texto-linea";
        botonLinea.className = "boton-linea";
        
        textoLinea.textContent = text;
        botonLinea.appendChild(addDeleteBtn());
        linea.appendChild(textoLinea);
        linea.appendChild(botonLinea);
        contenedor.appendChild(linea);

        alert.style.display = "none";
       
    }
```

Y por último, quitaría en la función **addDeleteBtn** la línea

```
deleteBtn.style.margin = "10px 0px 0px 605px";
```

Con esto, para cada línea añadida creo un div con estilo flex y dentro dos divs, el de la derecha con un ancho fijo para meter el botón y el de la izquierda con **auto** para que ocupe todo el espacio restante.

Además, ahora con las clases linea, texto-linea y boton-linea podrás darle estilo más fácilmente.

Comment: Sin duda, tu aportación me ha servido de mucho, ahora se ve muchísimo más ordenado y mejor maquetado. El problema es que ahora la tarea ocupa todo el ancho de la página, y yo buscaba algo más estilo "mensaje de whatsapp", es decir, que el texto esté encerrado en un bloque y que al llegar al límite del bloque saltase a la siguiente línea, conflicto que no doy solucionado todavía. ¿Sabrías como complementar esto a tu aporte? Gracias de antemano!

Comment: Todo depende de lo que quieras hacer, pero algo sencillo sería encerrar todo lo que está dentro del body en un div y a este darle  una clase que limite el ancho, por ejemplo algo así:

.visor{
 position: relative;
 width: 80%;
 left: 50%;
 transform: translate(-50%);
 background-color: green;
}

Le he puesto el ancho 80% porque es el que tú le habías puesto al form, si lo quieres más estrecho, cambia el del form también

Comment: Si no lo quieres todo más corto, sólo la lista, cambia sólo la clase **resultados** con algo como lo que te he puesto arriba

Comment: Perfecto! Era justo como lo pretendía maquetar. Mil gracias por tu aporte!

Comment: Me alegro de haberte ayudado